# Ruby Rails _without_ ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm looking for any pointers on how to write a rails web app without ActiveRecord.

A doc or an example of a (not too complex) web app using storage backends other than a relational database would be greatly appreciated.

It's not clear on what should be implemented in the model classes in order to make the rails app work without the ActiveRecord layer.

Thanks,

Comment: Just curious...are you doing this for any particular reason?

Comment: Of course, I hava a web app to develop but there is no relational db backend ...

Comment: Yes, turns out I misread your question. Thanks for the double clarification. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this will seem a lot easier with Rails 3. Rails team spent a lot of efforts on ORM agnosticism when pushing to beta. They've created a public API (`ActiveModel`) for different ORMs to implement, so that an ORM can serve as a drop-in replacement for `ActiveRecord`. That way you'll just be able to define models in terms of your ORM without any extra efforts.

`DataMapper` already has an implementation of `ActiveModel` in [dm-rails](http://github.com/datamapper/dm-rails), and there'll be more to come.

See [this post](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/rails-and-merb-merge-orm-agnosticism-part-5-of-6/) by Yehuda Katz for details.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it's possible, here, for example, MongoMapper is used instead of ActiveRecord:

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/07/23/getting-started-with-mongomapper-and-rails/

Comment: Great, this seems pretty close to what I was looking for ! Thanks for the pointer